# d3 Topojson debugging transformations

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

Are there general d3/topojson debugging hints? I am relatively new to the format and have made a visualization through d3 for the US states. The JavaScript and d3 works for a topojson file I had on hand. However, when changing the file to something with more descriptions, no errors or issues were thrown, but I got the following result:

[image]

I do not want to post the entire json because it is quite large, but are there any debugging practices you would recommend when dealing with topojson visualization in d3? I am assuming the error is with the transformation, but I am unsure how to approach and remedy the issue.

```
var svg = d3.select("#map1");
var path = d3.geoPath();
svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "states")
   .selectAll("path")
   .data(topojson.feature(x, x.objects.states).features)
   .enter()
```

Update: Not looking for anyone to explicitly debug my code. I need to understand what is going wrong for additional projects. But if this is helpful, here's a very small sample of the overall topojson:

```
{"type":"Topology",
 "arcs":[[[1071248,837478],[27,35],[64,83],[44,75],[38,57],[42,29],[32,-10],[38,-33],[35,-57],[32,-447],[-10,-33],[-28,6],[-216,188],[-85,81],[-13,26]],... ]
 "transform":{"scale":[0.00008503679331736181,0.00005379922226014208],
              "translate":[-179.148909,-14.548699000000001]},
 "objects":{"states":{"type":"GeometryCollection",
                      "geometries":[ {"arcs":[[[0]],[[1]],[[2]],[[3]],[[4]],[[5]],[[6,7,8,9,10]]],
                                      "type":"MultiPolygon",
                                      "properties":{"STATEFP":"01",
                                                    "STUSPS":"AL",
                                                    "NAME":"Alabama"}},...
```

Update2: This is the topojson that worked.

```
{"type":"Topology",
 "bbox":[-56.77775821661018,12.469025989284091,942.7924311762474,596.9298966319916],
 "transform":{"scale":[0.009995801851947097,0.005844667153098606],
              "translate":[-56.77775821661018,12.469025989284091]},
 "objects":{"states":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[0,1,2,3,4]],"id":"05089"},....
```

They are both topojson format and can be validated through [mapshaper.org](http://%20mapshaper.org), but are slightly different. Would anyone be able to explain the differences.

Comment: You could try loading the topojson file at [mapshaper.org](http://mapshaper.org).

Comment: I've tried verifying the topojson file in a few map viewers such as that. They all return the map in the correct format

Comment: If you include portions of your topojson it might help. A little of the beginning and end of the file should help. Also, including your d3 projection parameters could help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the transform properties were just off. The lines were being generated 1/1000 of the length they should have been for the size of my svg. Because the line has a certain required thickness, it just looks like some blobs; the map was correctly generating.

I guess to answer my own question, just play around with topojson properties until it resembles something you want. If the JavaScript is not crashing, assume the map has loaded correctly (but maybe not to your standards)

General checklist:

- Makes sure file is in right topojson format (This can be confirmed and even converted on [mapshaper.org](http://mapshaper.org) )
- Make sure topojson file is correctly loading. This can be tested with some `console.log`'s
- Make sure the data features are pointing to the right objects for the topojson. For me this was `x.objects.states`
- If the map is loading successfully, but looks wrong, consider abnormalities in 'transform'